# GLSL - Weird syntax error "<"

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to use a  shader but it keeps telling me this error on both fragment and vertex shader:

```
error(#132) Syntax error: "<" parse error
```

vertex shader

```
varying vec4 diffuse;
varying vec4 ambient;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 halfVector;
 
void main()
{
    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
 
    halfVector = gl_LightSource[0].halfVector.xyz;
 
    diffuse = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse;
    ambient = gl_FrontMaterial.ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
    ambient += gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient;

    gl_Position = ftransform();
 
}
```

fragment shader

```
varying vec4 diffuse,ambient;
varying vec3 normal,halfVector;
 
void main()
{
    vec3 n,halfV,lightDir;
    float NdotL,NdotHV;
 
    lightDir = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position);
 
    vec4 color = ambient;
 
    n = normalize(normal);
 
    NdotL = max(dot(n,lightDir),0.0);
    if (NdotL > 0.0) {
        color += diffuse * NdotL;
        halfV = normalize(halfVector);
        NdotHV = max(dot(n,halfV),0.0);
        color += gl_FrontMaterial.specular *
                gl_LightSource[0].specular *
                pow(NdotHV, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
    }
 
    gl_FragColor = color;
 
}
```

Code to read shaders:

```
bool Shader::load(string vertex , string fragment)
{
    // These will hold the shader's text file data
    string vshader, fshader;

    // Make sure the user passed in a vertex and fragment shader file
    if(!vertex.length() || !fragment.length()) return false;

    // If any of our shader pointers are set, let's free them first.
    if(VertexShader || FragmentShader || ProgramObject) Release();

    // Here we get a pointer to our vertex and fragment shaders
    VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Now we load the shaders from the respective files and store it in a string.
    vshader = LoadTextFile(vertex.c_str());
    fshader = LoadTextFile(fragment.c_str());

    if(vshader == "" || fshader == "") return false;

    // Do a quick switch so we can do a double pointer below
    const char *vvshader = vshader.c_str();
    const char *ffshader = fshader.c_str();

    // Now this assigns the shader text file to each shader pointer
    glShaderSource(VertexShader, 1, &vvshader, NULL);
    glShaderSource(FragmentShader, 1, &ffshader, NULL);

    // Now we actually compile the shader's code
    glCompileShader(VertexShader);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShader);

    printInfoLog(VertexShader);
    printInfoLog(FragmentShader);

    // Next we create a program object to represent our shaders
    ProgramObject = glCreateProgram();

    // We attach each shader we just loaded to our program object
    glAttachShader(ProgramObject, VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ProgramObject, FragmentShader);

    // Our last init function is to link our program object with OpenGL
    glLinkProgram(ProgramObject);

    printInfoLog(ProgramObject);

    // Now, let's turn off our current shader.
    glUseProgram(0);

    return true;

}


string Shader::LoadTextFile(string file)
{
    // Open the file passed in
    ifstream fin(file.c_str());

    // Make sure we opened the file correctly
    if(!fin) return "";

    string line = "";
    string text = "";

    // Go through and store each line in the text file within a "string" object
    while(getline(fin, line))
    {
        text = text + "\n" + line;
    }

    // Close our file
    fin.close();

    // Return the text file's data
    return text;
}
```

However, if I try another shader is works just fine! I really don't know why.

Comment: Can you show the source of a working shader? I suggest just printing the strings vvshader and ffshader (or use some gl debugger) to make sure you are actually sending the source code you think you are using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error and the lack of a `<` token in your shader sources suggests that glShaderSource is reading into trailing garbage at the end of the strings.

This sounds like a subtle problem known to the seasoned developers but that can stump the newbies. glShaderSource either expects zero terminated strings and a NULL pointer for the length array or you're passing an array with lengths so that the strings don't need to be 0 terminated. Technically std::string::c_str should give access to a zero terminated string, but it seems in your case it doesn't.

Anyway the simple solution is to provide a length array, so that glShaderSource doesn't read into trailing garbage:

```
// Do a quick switch so we can do a double pointer below
const char *vvshader = vshader.c_str();
const char *ffshader = fshader.c_str();
const GLint lenvshader = vshader.length();
const GLint lenfshader = fshader.length();

// Now this assigns the shader text file to each shader pointer
glShaderSource(VertexShader, 1, &vvshader, &lenvshader);
glShaderSource(FragmentShader, 1, &ffshader, &lenfshader);
```