# GLSL Weird Syntax Error

Tags: qt, opengl

I have the same error with this link:
[GLSL - Weird syntax error "<"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624318/glsl-weird-syntax-error)

But I am using Qt OpenGL so my code is like this.

```
if (!m_program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, shaderPath + "default.vert"))
   qDebug() << "specular vertex shader connot be loaded or compiled!";

if (!m_program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, shaderPath + "default.frag"))
    qDebug() << "specular fragment shader connot be loaded or compiled!";

if (!m_program.link())
    qDebug() << "specular vertex shader connot be loaded or compiled!";
```

The code actualy work well on my Win 8.1 Desktop PC but not on Win 7 notebook. I read the solution in the link but Qt already does the reading the code from file and compiling parts for me. What can I do?

Comment: Try #include <QDebug>

Comment: I am getting this error "error(#132) Syntax error: "<" parse error". There is nothing about qDebug(). It is already working. Please look at the link.

Comment: The only "<" I can see in your small code segement is in qDebug() << "..."

Comment: Please look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624318/glsl-weird-syntax-error For a reason it gaves this error from shader code. It is not about my source code.

Comment: Can you post your actual shader code? Also in addition to the error message about the syntax do any of your debug statements also print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I don't know why but adding version directive in my shader code worked.

```
#version 150
```